# Converting Depth Image into open cv Mat format

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using a PMD camera to capture depth image in the below format

```
struct DepthData
{
    int      version;  
    std::chrono::microseconds timeStamp;       
    uint16_t                  width;           
    uint16_t                  height;          
    Vector of uint_16          exposureTimes;   
    Vector of DepthPoint     points;          //!< array of points
};
```

Depth point structure looks like this

```
struct DepthPoint
{
    float x;                 //!< X coordinate [meters]
    float y;                 //!< Y coordinate [meters]
    float z;                 //!< Z coordinate [meters]
    float noise;             //!< noise value [meters]
    uint16_t grayValue;      //!< 16-bit gray value
    uint8_t depthConfidence; //!< value 0 = bad, 255 = good
};
```

And I am trying to convert it into opencv mat data structure. Below is the code.
But it is throwing an exception. Kindly help

```
const int imageSize = w * h;

Mat out = cv::Mat(h, w, CV_16UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));

const Scalar S;


for (int h = 0; h < out.rows; h++)
{
  //printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", point.at(h).grayValue);
  for (int w = 0; w < out.cols; w++)
  {
    //printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", point.at(h).grayValue);
    out.at<cv::Vec3f>(h,w)[0] = point[w].x;
    out.at<cv::Vec3f>(h, w)[1] = point[w].y;
    out.at<cv::Vec3f>(h, w)[2] = point[w].z;

  }
}

imwrite("E:/softwares/1.8.0.71/bin/depthImage1.png", out);
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Are you trying to create a depth image? Then you probably don't need 3 channels. You would need to compute depth on your own from `x, y, z` coordinates and set it to a pixel in a single-channel image.

Comment: I am trying to save the depth data in png format and I am capturing the data using royale API for PMD camera.  Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I think this is not related to the question itself, but it seems you have a mistake in the loop. You seem to iterate over `point`. I assume it is an array of `DepthPoint` objects. But you only iterate values with index from `0` to `out.cols`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be doing a couple of things wrong.

You are creating an image of type `CV_16UC3` which is a 3 channel 16 bit unsigned char image. Then in `out.at<cv::Vec3f>(h,w)[0]` you try to read part of it as a vector of 3 floats. You should probably create your image as a float image instead.

For further details please provide the exception. It will be easier to help.

**UPD:** If you just want a depth image, create an image like this:

```
Mat out = cv::Mat::zeros(h, w, CV_16UC1);
```

Then in every pixel:

```
out.at<uint16_t>(h, w) = depth_point.grayValue;
```

Comment: I want to save my image as a 16 bit png image. How can i access the gray values in the structure DepthPoint instead of using the float values?

Comment: I have tried it. But i am getting the below exception.    OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (total() == 0 || data != NULL) in cv::Mat::Mat, file E:\softwares\opencv-3.1.0\opencv-3.1.0\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 410

Comment: Mat out = cv::Mat(h, w, CV_16UC1); The exception is gone when i changed the code like this. But I am getting an empty image.

Comment: yep, sorry. Updated the initializer. Now using `zeros` function from `Mat`. The image is probably not empty. It is just very dark. Try to multiply all your numbers by smth like `1000` to see something on the image.

Comment: The reason is that the max value of your 16 bit unsigned int is `65535` and all values will be scaled to `[0, 65535]`. So if your values are something like `1000` (e.g. depth is in mm) then the image will be completely dark.